# Is there any 'Ubuntu 10.04 desktop' theme available to make it look like Windows 7 or Windows8?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, themes

I want to know is there any theme available make it 'Ubuntu 10.04 desktop'  look like Windows 7 or Windows8 ?

Comment: http://www.pcworld.com/article/2028896/how-to-make-ubuntu-linux-look-like-windows-7.html ?

Comment: As per community policy, 10.04 related desktop questions are regarded as off-topic.

Comment: @fossfreedom - It is about Ubuntu - this is *(one of)* Ubuntu's forums. **Stop nit-picking!**

Comment: @wilf - if you want to discuss this further, please join me in the general chat room.  Thanks.

Comment: @wilf - I've just realised this was a duplicate anyway and  have linked it as such.

Comment: Alright @fossfreedom... It does refer to Windows 8 though - http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-get-Windows-8-Metro-like-Theme-in-Ubuntu-13-04-350429.shtml could help... Penfold Shush! [danger mouse related joke, sorry...](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c88f455192559b06f95d006abfe33f9f?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG)